# How to test an internal exception in test class?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am testing a class (say A) in which another method from another class (say B) is being called. B throws an exception but the catch block for that method just logs an error. How do I assert that an exception is being thrown internally?? Any suggestions on this will help.

Class A:

```
    public class A {

    private static Logger logger;

    private B b;

    public A() {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("A");
        b = new B();
    }

    public void methodA() {
        b.methodB();
        logger.info("A");
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B {

    private static Logger logger;

    public B() {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("B");
    }

    public void methodB() {
        try {
            throw new Exception("NULL");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.info("Exception thrown");
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
 @Test
    public void testException() {
        A a = new A();
        a.methodA();
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> b.methodB());
    }
```

This is what I wrote for the test.
I receive the following error:

```
Expected java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

I want to make sure that an exception is being thrown in the code.

Comment: You catch exception inside method so what you expected to be thrown outside method? It doesn't make sens but you may try to mock Logger and check if info method was called with `"Exception thrown"` but again ... testing internals doesn't make sens at all

Comment: Maybe your method instead being void should return result which would tell if it's fail or succeded or just throw errors outside

Comment: Why exactly do you want to test this? It makes no difference to the behaviour of the class, *unless* what appears in the logs is part of your API. In that case, inject the `LoggerFactory` and mock it and the `Logger`. Then you can verify that the expected call was made to the `Logger`. By the way, why are you initialising a `static` field in your constructors?

Comment: That's how the current project is setup.

Comment: The method doesn't return anything just a bunch of logs

Comment: You are also testing A and B at the same time. `A` should not be creating an instance of `B`, an instance of `B` should be injected into `A`, then you can check that `A.methodA()` calls `B.methodB()`.

Comment: My Initial statement was assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> a.methodA()); Since that did not return anything I tried diffferent things

Answer (score 1):

Class B is just badly designed, don't do this. Alternatively, if you really want to ignore the error, then simply write a test which wraps your call to B with a try/catch block and use the fail(String) assertion method to cause the test to fail if the exception is NOT swallowed. As written in your example this should ALWAYS pass, but I assume in a more realistic scenario that might be in doubt.

Honestly though, don't write a class like B! If you really MUST NOT ever throw the exception for some reason, then you should at least return an Optional<> or something, say carrying a flag indicating whether or not the exception happened. At least that will be fully testable.